# automatically divide a table into several tables, applying 'filter'

Tags: r

I'm trying to separate a table into several mini tables, according to its vectors of one column.

And trying to do it automatically, using loops or whatever. And I don't have any idea..

I have datatable called 'number2017' shaped like

```
year  quarter number
2017    1      2
2017    3      4
2017    1      3
2017    2      8
.
.
```

and I have tables like  `'number2018' 'number2019' 'numbers2020'....`

What I'm trying to do is, I'm going to separate 'number2017' according to its vectos of 'qurter', and make tables like 'number20171' 'number20172' 'number20173' 'number'20173'.

Name 'number20171' means it contains only 'qurter==1' of 'number2017'. And also 'number20172' means this table contains only 'qurter==2' of 'number2017'.

And I'm gonna do this to all the datatables. So finally I'll get list like

```
[number20171, number20172, number20173, number 20174, number20181, number20182, number20183, number20184, number20191........]
```

Do you got it?

I just don't get how to let out multiple tables with serial number using loops.

```
for(x in c(1,2,3,4){
paste("number2017",x <-filter(number2017, quarter==x)
}
```

this is just what I tried, but failed.

How can I do this job?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes thank you! It works perfectly! :)

Comment: @RonakShah Oh absolutely! I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the data in a list based on `pattern` of the dataframe name and use `lapply` to `split` each dataframe based on `quarter`.

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = "number\\d+"))

total_list <- unlist(lapply(names(list_df), function(x) {
                      df <- list_df[[x]]
                      temp_df <- split(df, df$quarter)
                      names(temp_df) <- paste0(x, seq_along(temp_df))
                      temp_df
               }), recursive = FALSE)
```

This will return you a list of dataframes, if needed in separate dataframe, we can use `list2env`

```
list2env(total_list, .GlobalEnv)
```